# Why is it that sometimes defining a value in Haskell changes its type?

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have

```
mylist = [1..5]
```

It's clear that

```
[1..5] :: (Num t, Enum t) => [t]
```

but why is it that

```
mylist :: [Integer]
```

instead of

```
mylist :: (Num t, Enum t) => [t]
```

in GHCi? (At least as reported by `:t`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular example is defaulted to `Integer` because of the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonomorphismRestriction).

BTW this does **not** happen in GHCi, anymore: since ghc-7.8 it uses `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` by default.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I saw that 7.8.1 change described in the link; needless to say, I'm using a previous version. Thanks!